# Валидация XML с использованием XSD: 2 одинаковых тега в разных местах XML

Tags: xml, валидация, xsd, validate

XML содержит 2 одинаковых тега в разных местах.
В схему валидации добавил проверку для обоих тегов, но при валидации получаю ошибку:

> Duplicated definition for: 'reference'

Вопросы:

1. Можно ли как-то в схеме валидации описать, что у меня 2 одинаковых тега в разных местах XML?
2. Или можно ли исключить из проверки один из этих тегов, чтобы не было этой ошибки?

XML содержит 2 одинаковых тега в разных местах:

```xml
<message>
    <reference type="document">11111111111</reference>
    <currency>XXX</currency>
    <amount>0.00</amount>
    <valuedate>2023.05.01</valuedate>
    ...
    <reference type="out">2222222222222</reference>
</message>
```

В схему валидации добавил проверку для обоих тегов:

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="message">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="reference">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                ...
                <xs:element name="reference">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: А может namespace добавить к тегу другой?

Comment: @megorit Это как: добавить другой namespace? Я новичок в XSD, сорри.

Comment: Кстати, не сильно много в `XSD` понимаю но, а где у вас неймспейсы в примере для валидации? Я когда работал с `SOAP` (клиентская часть), там namespace'ы были обязательны.

Comment: В запросе тоже нужно неймспейсы прописывать, по такому же принципу. Схемы я как раз не писал, а пользовался ими для валидации своих запросов, так что на счёт них точно не скажу.

Comment: В XSD точно есть способ передавать одинаковые теги. Я контейнеры отправлял так.

Comment: У меня в описании головного тега прописано так:    

```
<message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance". 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="tmp.xsd">
```

Comment: Чем пользуетесь для работы с XML/XSD? Во многих средах можно автоматически сгенерировать схему по xml. Например, в Visual Studio.

Comment: Есть и онлайн-генераторы схем. Воспользуйтесь несколькими, они могут выдавать разные схемы. Выберите наиболее подходящую.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov использую VSCode. Я как раз начал с генерации xsd с помощью online-генератора. Но генератор сформировал xsd схему, в которой только одно описание тега <reference>.     
Я попробовал в xsd на месте, где тег <reference> появляется второй раз: написать так  <xs:any minOccurs="1"/>, но теперь ошибка валидации следующая "cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'reference'".